# How to create buttresses of a tree?

Tags: modeling

So I'm learning how to model trees using the Skin modifier. There's a particular tree that has buttresses at the base. Can anyone give me some tips on how I might model these? I've looked at a few Youtube tutorials like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDXB3SDQHYw However, it only gives me round roots. I want to create flake-shape buttresses like the photos below.

[image]

[image]